# Usage of a/the articles, when an object is determined by "that...."

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

In "Cambridge preparation to TOEFL"'93 book I've found the phrase:

*The old woman made a special tea with __ herb that smelled of oranges.*

The correct answer is "an". But the woman added the specific herb, not just a herb.
The herb is determined by the phrase "that smelled of oranges".

Would this phrase be grammatically/semantically correct, if we use "the" instead?

If there is any difference, tell me the British version of this.

Comment: Both are quite acceptable. *An* is less specific, as you pointed out, but perfectly fine, even with the further description. If there was only one herb that smelled of oranges, *the* would be appropriate (but not strictly necessary); or *the* can be used to emphasize that the herb smelled of oranges. As a native speaker, I would have chosen *an*, because to me, it reads primarily as an herb tea, not tea made with orange-scented herbs.

Comment: Thank you, medica.
My concern here was that the herb is determined by the fact that the woman took it in her hand and drop it into the tea cup.
So there is only one herb that passed through her hands from a jar to the cup.
From your answer I see that "the" is still acceptable, even if my argument is wrong. So to pass the TOEFL one needs a bit of luck...

Comment: True, there is only one herb, but *an* is singular. *That*... I don't *think* '*that*' determines which determiner one should use; *that* can often be dropped without changing much, e.g. "...a special tea with __ herb smelling of oranges." (yes, I had to change smelled, but I hope you see my point. I'm not a linguist, btw. Maybe one will come along and give a more definitive answer. :)

Comment: It's not "that" that determines the article in your example. Using the definite article "the" assumes that the reader is familiar with the herb that is being talked about, i.e. they can identify the specific herb that smelled of oranges. Otherwise it must be the indefinite "an", which I think is the most likely option here.

Comment: Thank you, BillJ. But "the reader is familiar with the smth. that is being talked about" is not the only rule that determines the choice of articles.

Comment: Prototypically, the definite article "the" functions as determiner in NP structure with the sole meaning of identifying that the head is sufficient in the context to identify the referent. If I say "the herb that smelled of oranges", I assume you know which herb I'm referring to.

Comment: BillJ,
"I assume you know which herb I'm referring to." My assumption here: "The one that the woman dropped into the cup."

Comment: The point is that there may well have been more than one herb that smelled of oranges. Only if the reader is familiar with the referent of the particular "herb" that is being discussed can the definite article "the" be used. Your book is correct.

Comment: The reader is familiar with the referent of the particular "herb". It is exactly the verb that the old woman dropped into the cup.

Comment: Is this one sentence the only context for this exercise? If so, it's a terrible question since either *an* or *the* are possible. The choice between the two usually depends on what the speaker assumes about the listener, as BillJ has said.

Comment: Outmind, just because we know it's the specific herb dropped into the cup isn't enough to satisfy what @BillJ is saying. You need to have context on the herb put in the tea other than that it is being put in the tea. If I picked up a hat and showed it to you and said "this is the hat" you would know specifically which hat I was talking about (the one in my hand), but "the" would still be wrong without any other context. So while others have pointed out that both "an" and "the" are grammatically correct, "the" assumes we've been given context that we have not been given,  "an" does not.

Answer (score -1):

> The old woman made a special tea with __ herb that smelled of oranges.

Note that the herb *smelled* -- past tense.  This means that the smell was experienced at the time the tea was being made, vs referring, say, to an herb which "everyone knows" smells of oranges.

Thus, "*that* herb that *smelled* of oranges" would be inappropriate, unless the story had somehow previously introduced the herb and mentioned its smell.  On the other hand, "*that* herb that *smells* of oranges" would be quite acceptable, as it implies that the reader, if he's aware of the nature of such herbs, knows what is meant.

On the other hand, "*an* herb that *smelled* of oranges" works, since no prior knowledge is required, but "*an* herb that *smells* of oranges" is at least stretching things.

"*The* herb ..." is similar to the *that* case.

Comment: Curious -- three downvotes and no one has explained what's wrong.

Comment: thank you for your analysis